# Typescript project cannot find module after vscode update

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, amd

VS code was harassing me every time I start it up to update so this morning I did and now many ts files cannot find modules anymore.

Many files have statements like:

```
 import Mustache = require("mustache");
```

These files do not have a statement like:

```
 ///<reference path="./typings/mustache.d.ts" />
```

But since another file in the project has that statement it used to be no problem. Somehow; once I referenced "mustache" somewhere I didn't need to repeat the process in other files and could directly require it.

I updated to:

```
Version 1.6.0
shell 1.3.7
node 6.5.0
```

If anyone could help out on how to solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

task.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc.cmd",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

node tsc:

```
C:\Users\me>tsc.cmd
Version 1.8.10
```

tsc.exe:

```
C:\Users\me>tsc.exe
Version 1.8.2
```

In the root of the source directory I added a index.d.ts with the following content:

```
///<reference path="./typings/mustache.d.ts" />
///<reference path="./typings/jquery.2.1.3.d.ts" />
///<reference path="./typings/settings.typing.ts" />
```

But files can still not find mustache unless I add the type definition in the file it self.

Uninstalled vs code and installed it again but same problem (same version)

**[UPDATE]**

Downloaded [1.5.3](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_5) and all the problems went away

Comment: Does `tsc` work on the command line? PS: give http://alm.tools/ a go (I wrote it).

Comment: @basarat Yes, the compile works without errors.

Comment: @basarat I will check out the alm tools project later (put it in my todo list). Thank you for the help. Currently I have donwgraded to 1.5.3 and all the problems went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the base of your source files (i.e., src/ ) make an index.d.ts file with all the ///'s

This continues to work for me even on:

Version 1.6.0
Commit e52fb0b...
Renderer 52.0
Node 6.5.0

You could try [installing the second latest version](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_5) and see if the problems you are having with the latest version still persist.

Comment: I think something is proper broken with 1.6.0 e52fb0bc8... For example; I have a file Filter.ts that requires util `import u = require("util");` They are both in the same directory but vscode says `cannot find module 'util'`

Comment: If they are in the same directory then the path is './util' not 'util'. The rule is that any short path is seen as /node_modules/..., while relative path requires the dot "." which indicates current directory. So if you had a src/ directory, then referring to src/util.ts is the same as ./util.ts from within src.

Comment: I have made a small change to your answer and added the solution that worked for me.